# Updating scenes in advance while still rendering previous frame

Tags: java, multithreading, opengl, lwjgl

I'm currently working on a multi-threading safe rendering system and I would like to know your thoughts on how to correctly update the next step in the game world while the previous scene is currently rendering. Currently I am using LWJGL Opengl Bindings with Java. Here is pseudocode for my game loop as it is currently set up (which is probably just a basic loop that most people are familiar with):

```
//DrawingLayers are wrappers for in game entities and has an update 
//and render method

game-loop:
    addInputEventsToInputStack()

    removeCompletedDrawingLayers()

    foreach layer in DrawingLayerQueue :
        layer.update(deltaTime) //update position/color/size for entity
        layer.render() //performs OpenGL calls
        if(layer.isCompleted):
            addToCompletedDrawingLayersList()


    swapBuffers() //blocks until scene is fully rendered
goto game-loop
```

My problem lies in the `swapBuffers()` method as it blocks until the scene is rendered which means I cannot perform any updates while that is going on. My thought on how to get around this is to:

Have a copy of all DrawingLayers that I use for updating the state of the entities and have the other copy as a reference for the rendering thread. And while a frame is rendering, kick off a thread just before `swapBuffers()` to update the copy that is not in use.

I'm wary of this approach as I believe creating the copies before every frame would slow the system down more than I would like.

Does my approach make sense, and if not, do you guys have any recommendations for how to do this? I'm open to a complete restructuring.

**Updated:** Based on datenwolf's suggestion I've changed my gameloop to the following:

```
//DrawingLayers are wrappers for in game entities and has an update 
//and render method


//A future for the pre-processing task
Future preProcess = null

game-loop:

    //Update: checks if we have a preprocessed update to wait for
    //and waits for it to complete
    if(preProcess != null):
        preProcess.get()
        preProcess = null

    addInputEventsToInputStack()

    removeCompletedDrawingLayers()

    foreach layer in DrawingLayerQueue :
        layer.render() //performs OpenGL calls
        if(layer.isCompleted):
            addToCompletedDrawingLayersList()

    //UPDATE: the following just calls all the update methods for the layers
    // in a new thread
    preProcess = executorService.submit(new UpdateRunnable())

    swapBuffers() //blocks until scene is fully rendered
goto game-loop
```

So far with this I've got a significant improvement in performance. There may be some race condition issues that I cant see, but overall Im happy with this improvement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> in the swapBuffers() method as it blocks until the scene is rendered

The blocking of the buffer swap is only partial by finishing the rendering. It usually also blocks due to wait for the retrace. However OpenGL guarantees you, that after any drawing command returns, the buffers accessed by it can be safely modified without any pending rendering operations being impaired. The implementation is required to make copies or copy-on-write mappings to all data.

Or in short terms: Just modify the data in the buffers. As soon as drawing calls (glDrawArrays, glDrawElements) return it's safe to do so.

Comment: I've updated my original question with the changes I made based on your comment.